# jquery: css first-child not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="item-box-desc">
<h1>title</h1>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
</div>

<div class="item-box-desc">
<h1>title</h1>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
</div>
```

And the following jquery:

```
$('.item-box-desc p:first-child').css({
    'font-weight': 'bold'
})
```

And I want to be able to apply bold to the first element of `<p>` for each div.  In that case 1 and 3 should be in bold. But my code doesn't apply it.

Comment: That is because the paragraphs *aren't* the first child: the `<h1>` is.

Comment: Why not just use plain CSS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with plain CSS and the [:nth-of-type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

```css
.item-box-desc p:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-box-desc">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>

<div class="item-box-desc">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

`:first-child` (in both CSS and jQuery) won't work because the first `<p>` element isn't the first child of the `<div>`; the `<h1>` is.